# What is the recommended way to use ActiveRecord in CodeIgniter models?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I believe this has been asked before with different words, I already did a search on similar questions and found:

- [CodeIgniter instance of model class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332552/codeigniter-instance-of-model-class)
- [Usind models in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228079/using-models-in-codeigniter)

However, being mainly a C# developer I sometimes find difficult to separate previous knowledge of the language with other tools, such as PHP. My philosophy is to follow the de facto standards of the language itself.

That being said, I have used several ORM tools such as Db4objects, DevExpress XPO, EntityFramework and many more. What I find quite different from the .Net approach to the ActiveRecord implementation in CodeIgniter is how Models are used, for example, in CI you´d normally have a model instance loaded and use it almost like a static method to do all operations and then pass some sort of data as parameter either as an array or several parameters:

```
$this->load->model('User_model');
$this->User_model->save($username, $password);
```

Or:

```
$this->load->model('User_model');
$this->User_model->save(array(
  'user' => 'theuser',
  'password' => 'thepassword'
));
```

So you´ll end up using the same instance to do all operations, but sometimes that can be confusing, especially coming from another object oriented language, I often find myself doing this:

```
$user = new User_model();
$user->username = 'theusername';
$user->password = 'thepassword';
$user->save();
```

As seen, I invoke a method on an instance to do actual work, the save method would look like:

```
function save() {
  $this->db->set('username', $this->username);
  $this->db->set('username', md5($this->password));
  $this->db->insert('User');
}
```

Is there some recommended standard to do this kind of operations in CI? I do know there must be pros and cons but I don´t see anything about this topic on the CI Documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The object automatically create whenever you load the model/library/helper in CI.There is no need to create it again.It is easier and recommented aproach

Comment: This is the official tutorial for this - ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html‎

Comment: If you need to do like 
$user = new User_model();
$user->username = 'theusername';
$user->password = 'thepassword'; this, why should you use framework? You can do it in core php

Comment: I do understand there's an instance created when you load the model, my question goes more to the fact of using methods with parameters to do the actual CRUD operations or have a typed model where you invoke methods that take instance values to do the underlying database operations.

Comment: Yes. CI sucks in this case, adding all to the super object. Moreover, CI doesn't have active record. It has query builder only. Don't let the documentation fool you.

Comment: @itachi Then I guess as you say the documentation fools us, nonetheless CI still is a better approach to web development than plain PHP IMHO, we have to work around the limitations I guess

Comment: For better approach, use laravel, yii, zend, symfony. Any of them is better than CI.